# How do you make a multiple variable frequency table in R when not all values are present in all columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, frequency

I'd like to make a frequency table like this in R:

```
df = data.frame(aa = c(9,8,7,8), bb = c(9,7,9,8), cc = c(7,9,8,7))
apply(df, 2, table)

# outputs:  
#   aa bb cc
# 7  1  1  2
# 8  2  1  1
# 9  1  2  1
```

But, if one of the columns of `df` would have a count of 0 (e.g. if we change the above so that `df$cc` has no `9`) we'll get a list instead of a nice dataframe.

```
# example that gives a list
df = data.frame(aa = c(9,8,7,8), bb = c(9,7,9,8), cc = c(7,8,8,7))
apply(df, 2, table)
```

What's a simple way do something similar that will guarantee dataframe output regardless of the counts?

I can imagine a number of solutions that seem messy or hacked, for example, this produces the desired result:

```
# example of a messy but correct solution
df = data.frame(aa = c(9,8,7,8), bb = c(9,7,9,8), cc = c(7,8,8,7))
apply(df, 2, function(x) summary(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(df)))))
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What do you find "messy" about the solution you found? Looks fine to me. I can think of other solutions too, but whether or not they are "messy" seems pretty opinion-based. Can you give some objective criteria?

Comment: Maybe a solution that uses three or fewer functions? The solution I posted uses five. I know it seems arbitrary, but I thought there had to be a function somewhere that does (at least most of) what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer, though I still object to the lack of criteria. If we think of "tidy" as the opposite of "messy", then we should first tidy the input data into a long format. Then we can do a two-way `table`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather %>%
  with(table(value, key))
#      key
# value aa bb cc
#     7  1  1  2
#     8  2  1  2
#     9  1  2  0
```

Thanks to Markus for a base R version:

```
table(stack(df))
#       ind
# values aa bb cc
#      7  1  1  2
#      8  2  1  2
#      9  1  2  0
```

Comment: In baseR `table(stack(df))`

Comment: Man, I think I learned about `stack` from you yesterday and it's already coming in handy again. Great base R utility function!

Comment: Technically, `table(stack(df))` does not give back a dataframe, but `as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(df)))` did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: Tables aren't data frames. None of the examples in your question or in this answer give data frames, but `as.data.frame.matrix(...)` will get you a data frame.